# Custom serializer.py Connection closed by server

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

What i am trying to do - is to save post to the model with custom conditions. But each time im trying to save - i receive this error `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column violates not-null constraint` 
So far, i have tried editing my models, and adding null=True in parameters, but it doesn't seem to help. So what is the best way to solve the problem here? Also have to mention that it doesnt save `event_code` at all. But even if i will enter that code by hand - it still will give me "Connection closed by server." Also i dont know what this exactly means: `Exception Location:  /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/redis/asyncio/connection.py,` 
serialier.py:

```
class EventSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Events
        fields = ["cam_id", "vehicle_plate", "is_recognition", "is_confirmation", "vehicle_plate", "transit_block_time_min"]
    def save(self, **kwargs):
        instance = super().save(**kwargs)
        is_recognition = instance.is_recognition
        is_confirmation = instance.is_confirmation
        vehicle_plate = instance.vehicle_plate
        if CarParkItem.objects.filter(vehicle_plate=vehicle_plate).exists():
            instance.event_code = 1008
        elif BlackListItem.objects.filter(vehicle_plate=vehicle_plate).exists():
            instance.event_code = 1004
        elif is_recognition == False:
            instance.event_code = 1003
        elif is_recognition == True and is_confirmation == False:
            instance.event_code = 1006
        elif is_recognition == True and is_confirmation == True:
            instance.event_code = 1007
        instance.save()

        return instance
```

I have read about different approaches, but still dont know where and how to do it the best.

models that are used for it:

```
class BlackListItem(models.Model):
    vehicle_plate = models.CharField(max_length=999, db_index=True)
    valid_until = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=999)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.vehicle_plate

class CarParkItem(models.Model):
    vehicle_plate = models.CharField(max_length=999, db_index=True)
    valid_until = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=999)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.vehicle_plate

class WorkingMode(models.Model):

    PASSMODE_CHOICES = [
        ('pay_by_hour', 'pay_by_hour'),
        ('pay_by_interval', 'pay_by_interval'),
        ('closed', 'closed'),
    ]

    time_lte_hour = models.IntegerField()  # <
    time_gte_hour = models.IntegerField()  # > от
    time_lte_min = models.IntegerField()  # < до
    time_gte_min = models.IntegerField()  # >
    pass_mode = models.CharField(max_length=999, choices=PASSMODE_CHOICES)  # pay_by_hour | pay_by_interval | closed
    free_time_min = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    interval = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    transit_block_time_min = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True)
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    entry_fee = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=999)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.pass_mode
```

and `views.py`:

```
class EventModeSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Events.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EventSerializers
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it appears that the method `def save` should have been `async` as well, because my consumers.py code is also `async`. So i just added this:

```
 async def save(self, **kwargs):
        instance = super().save(**kwargs)
        is_recognition = instance.is_recognition
        is_confirmation = instance.is_confirmation
        vehicle_plate = instance.vehicle_plate
        if CarParkItem.objects.filter(vehicle_plate=vehicle_plate).exists():
            instance.event_code = 1008
        elif BlackListItem.objects.filter(vehicle_plate=vehicle_plate).exists():
            instance.event_code = 1004
        elif is_recognition == False:
            instance.event_code = 1003
        elif is_recognition == True and is_confirmation == False:
            instance.event_code = 1006
        elif is_recognition == True and is_confirmation == True:
            instance.event_code = 1007

        await asyncio.sleep(0)

        instance.save()
```

As i understand `asyncio.sleep(0)` is letting other coroutines (from `consumers.py`) to finish their job before going to next sten `instance.save`. The fact that other coroutines were not awaited and were not finished - was causing disconnect issue